# Passing control of console window to subprocess

Tags: c++, python, console, subprocess

I'm writing several Python scripts to manage building my C++ project. In one of these scripts, i will generate some header files, call GNU make with a makefile to build the project, then if successful, call gdb with my executable. My question is: How can i pass control of the console window to gdb, so i can interact with gdb directly without interference from Python? (Or perhaps pipe input and output through Python in real time.) And how would the Python script regain control of the console window after gdb has stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using subprocess, you can easily do that.

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen('gdb a.out', shell=True).communicate()
print 'test'
```

once you quit GDB, script will continue and 'test' will be printed.

Comment: Python is a lot simpler than i thought it was going to be.

Comment: @creXALBO: You don't need `shell=True` here. Simple `subprocess.call("gdb a.out".split())` works. `.communicate()` is usually called if you have an input string to pass to the subprocess or you want to get its stdout/stderr as a string (streams are assigned to `PIPE` in the `Popen` call in this case otherwise standard streams are inherited from the parent).